# Differ behavior of a junit-test based on success or no success

Tags: java, junit

I have some unit-tests which are setup by an @Before-method and cleaned by an @After-method. Now I want to do the @After-method something different if the test succeed than if it failed. How can I do this?

Comment: There was similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8119494/891391

Comment: Indeed it is, was very helpful

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a boolean flag in your @After method to decide what you want to do in case of success or failure. You can simply define a flag `isPassed` in your test class, turn it true if test case passed or turn it false in case of failure. Simply read this variable in your @After method and decide about what you need to do.

Comment: I think I'm searching for the one position where to add that isPassed = true, so I don't have to set it in every test